# Duplicate backup file is getting created in linux

Tags: linux, text-editors, ubuntu-14.04

I created a file called file2.txt in Linux, opened it in text editor and saved it. When I closed the text editor I see two files file2.txt and file2.txt~

I guess file2.txt~ is temporary file created when I am editing the file2.txt, but shouldn't it get removed when I finish saving and close the text editor?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same reaction the first time I saw that after migrating to Linux from Windows.  What you're seeing is a difference in naming conventions.

In Windows, files with extensions like `.tx~` are temporary working files that are often useless on their own.  They are generally deleted when you close the editor because they serve no function after the session.

Another extension, `.bak`, is often used for an automated backup copy of the original file so that you have the ability to roll back changes or recover if you later discover that you messed up editing.

In Linux, the `.txt~` is equivalent to the `.bak` file.  There would be no reason to create it if you were going to delete it on closure.

If you don't ever want a backup of the original file to be automatically created, your editor might have a setting to change this behavior.  In that case, it would behoove you to save edits under a new name, using the `Save as`, if you ever think you might need the previous version.